# ViewPager with 3 fragments load fragments on either side from the middle fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I have 3 fragments A,B and C. They are setup as tabs Tab A, Tab B, Tab C on and adapter as shown in my code below. I have setup my pager adapter such that the middle tab,Tab B loads the first

```
adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());
if (viewPager != null) {
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
}
```

This all works fine however when I navigate from Tab B to Tab C the first time it works perfectly. However when I navigate from Tab B to Tab A the first time its shows fragment B instead of A,when I navigate a second time (Tab B to Tab A  ) its now working as expected. How would I take care of this initial lag and mismatch of tabs.

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    int mNumOfTabs;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                FragmentA A = new FragmentA();
                return A;


            case 1:
                FragmentB B = new FragmentB();
                return B;

           case 2:
                FragmentC C = new FragmentC();
                return C;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to be returning a new Fragment each time you swipe between them? I think it makes more sense to keep hold of the Fragment instances between the pages, that way no data is lost.

Comment: The contents of the fragments change on swipe so I need new instances..cant afford to cache them

Comment: if you have 3 tabs just pass 3 to your adapter. why you use tabLayout.getTabCount()? is your tab count dynamic?

Comment: No tab count is static 3 in number

Answer (score 1):

To fragment is not reprinted can call the [setRetainInstance(true)](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean))

If you need to find a fragment of the tag, then you can create it with your tag via class FragmentTransaction.

In the case of ViewPager, FragmentPagerAdapter fragments appoints its tags can be seen in its [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.java)

There's a method make Fragment Name (int viewId, long id) assigns fragments tag types:

```
private static String makeFragmentName(int viewId, long id) {
        return "android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + id;
    }
```

where viewId - id ViewPager, id - the position of the fragment.

or use [setOffscreenPageLimit](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int))

`mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(mViewPager.getCount());`